# jQuery asynchronous issue undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

I am having difficulties with Javascript's asynchronous functions.
Code displayed below is so far almost entire code I have and I can't get it to work.

I ma trying to use Eventful API to pull some data from the server, and display it in my frontend which is created by jQuery.

So, the problem is following: function **search**, which is calling function **Eventful.prototype.searchanje** always ends up with undefined value, while a few seconds later, function searchanje console logs actual/recieved data.

I am fairly new to jQuery, and I was wondering if there is any kind of "template" for handling these things, concretely for waiting until the function returns value and then proceeding with next operations.
So far I have tried using deferred and promises, and read quite a lot tutorials and stackoverflow answers on similar subjects, but I can't get it to work properly.
Or, if deferred and promises are the right way to go, could you show me the way it is supposed to be done?

Thanks in advance

```
'use strict';

function Eventful(_name) {
var name = _name;
var appKey = 'appKey';
var that = this;

return {
    getName: function() {
        return name;
    },
    getAppKey: function() {
        return appKey;
    },
    search: function() {
        that.searchanje(appKey).then(function(oData) {
            console.log('oData');
        });
    }
};
}

Eventful.prototype.searchanje = function(appKey) {
var oArgs = {
    app_key: appKey,
    q: 'sport',
    where: 'Zagreb',
    date: '2013061000-2015062000',
    page_size: 5,
    sort_order: 'popularity',
};

EVDB.API.call('/events/search', oArgs, function(oData) {
    console.log(oData);
    return oData();
});
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
EVDB.API.call('/events/search', oArgs, function(oData) {
```

you are passing a CALLBACK function.  This function (the one that starts `function(oData)`) is not executed immediately.  It is executed asynchronously, when the result of your API call is returned.

Try putting `console.log()` statements around your code, and watch the order they appear in the console.  For example:

```
function Eventful(_name) {
    var name = _name;
    var appKey = 'appKey';
    var that = this;

    return {
        getName: function() {
            return name;
        },
        getAppKey: function() {
            return appKey;
        },
        search: function() {
            console.log('Search function called');
            that.searchanje(appKey).then(function(oData) {
                console.log('searchanje returned with data:');
                console.log('oData');
            });
        }
    };
}

Eventful.prototype.searchanje = function(appKey) { 
    console.log('function searchanje being called with appKey: ', appKey);
    var oArgs = {
        app_key: appKey,
        q: 'sport',
        where: 'Zagreb',
        date: '2013061000-2015062000',
        page_size: 5,
        sort_order: 'popularity',
    };

    console.log('Calling EVDB.API.call');
    EVDB.API.call('/events/search', oArgs, function(oData) {
        console.log('EVDB.API callback executing with data:');
        console.log(oData);
        return oData();
    });
    console.log('finished calling EVDB.API.call');
};
```

Comment: ok, do you have any proposal what to do how to continue from here? how to wait for that return value and then continue execution?

Comment: @Zorkan Yeah, you "do stuff" with your results inside the callback function

Comment: isn't that a way to end up in callback hell? not concretely for these couple of lines of code i got up here, but for more complex projects?

Comment: @Zorkan nope.. callback hell is when you *overuse* callbacks and end up with "rightward-drift".  If you get close to it, you start using Promises... but premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a better way ahead might be to "promisify" `EVDB.API.call()`.

```
(function(app_key) {
    var appKeyObj = { 'app_key': app_key },
    EVDB.API.callAsync = function(path, params) {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            EVDB.API.call(path, $.extend(appKeyObj, params), function(oData) {
                if (oData.error === "1") {
                    //translate oData.status and oData.description into a javascript Error object
                    // with standard .name and .message properties.
                    err = new Error(oData.description);
                    err.name = oData.status;
                    dfrd.reject(err);
                } else {
                    dfrd.resolve(oData);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})('myAppKey'); //hard-coded app key
```

Notes:

- The global namespace is avoided by :

  - using a self-executing anonymous wrapper
  - extending the `EVDB.API` namespace.
- The "Async" suffix for a promisified method has a precendent in bluebird
- From the little I understand of `EVDB.API`, `EVDB.API.call()` does just about everything, hence the single method `EVDB.API.callAsync()`. If necessary, further async methods could be added to `EVDB.API`
- You might choose to use a dedicated promise lib such as [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) or [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when) in place of jQuery, In addition to including the lib, mods to the above code would be minor.

Now, instead of calling `EVDB.API.call(path, params, callback)` you would call `EVDB.API.callAsync(path, params)` to be returned a Promise.

```
var params = {
    //app_key will be inserted automatically
    q: 'sport',
    where: 'Zagreb',
    date: '2013061000-2015062000',
    page_size: 5,
    sort_order: 'popularity'
};
EVDB.API.callAsync('/events/search', params).then(function(oData) {
    console.log(oData);
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```